# equivalent to link attribute in new share dialog

Tags: facebook, share

According to fb, the feed dialog is now deprecated, so I'm trying to use the new share dialog with open graph metas, all work however, the old feed dialog had a link attribute to point to any URL I want, my question is, is there anything similar in the new share dialog, the reason I need this is because my app is going to be loaded inside an iframe in different domains and I need to change the URL dynamically, thanks for any help